# Passing a value in my click() function

Tags: jquery, click

I have this piece of code,

```
<a href="#" id="addtoteam">
    Add to Team
</a>
```

, and if I click this link, a modal dialog will appear,

```
$('#addtoteam').click(function(){
      var url = '<?php echo BASEURL;?>';
      $( "#dialogbox" ).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: true,
        buttons: { 
                  "Use Registration Credits": function(){ 
                    // execute something here before redirecting it to another page, perhaps perform the updating of the registration_credits of each team here
                    window.location = url + '/administration/add_to_team/' + teamID +'/'+ playerID +'/?credit=1'; 
                  },
                  "Pay Extra Charge": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                  "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } 
                },
        width: 800
      });
    });
```

As you can see I have three buttons, take a look at the "Use Registration Credits" button, if it is chosen, it will redirect to another page, but what I want is if it redirects to other page, I want to have the url looking like this,

```
sample.com/administration/add_to_team/team_id/player_id?credit=1
```

Now my question is, is it possible to pass any value that can be assigned to a variable inside my `click()` function such that this value can be my team_id or player id? I hope I explained clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Where are `teamID` and `playerID` stored?

Comment: the `teamID` and `playerID` are actually from the controller. However, it is also available in the page where that code above reside. It is already part of the URL though.

Comment: How does the url look before you redirect then ?

Comment: actually my url looks like this before it will redirect, `sample.com/administration/new_players/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store parameters like team_id or player id in your element as attributes:

```
<a href="#" id="addtoteam" data-team-id="4" data-player-id="5" >
    Add to Team
</a>
```

then you get these with:

```
team_id = $(this).attr('data-team-id');
```

Hope It can help you

Comment: Uhhuh. I forgot about these, thanks. I will try this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selectors to grab data from anywhere on the page, also if you specifically wanted to take data from the 'clicked' link you can use `this` in context of the click event.

```
$('#addToTeam').on('click', function()
{
    var clicked = $(this);

    // Get the clicked links HREF value
    var href = clicked.attr('href');

    // Get the clicked links NAME value
    var name = clicked.attr('name');

    // And so on
    var data = clicked.attr('data-value')

});
```

To fully answer your question, you would want to add some more data to your `<a>` tags. For simple stuff such as ID's etc, I just put them in the HREF value, and then use the technique above to pull it for the clicked link. You can then append that value to a query string.

```
$('#addtoteam').click(function()
{
    id = $(this).attr('href');

    window.location = url + '/administration/add_to_team/' + id

});
```

As an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the URL from:

```
sample.com/administration/add_to_team/team_id/player_id
```

to :

```
sample.com/administration/add_to_team/team_id/player_id?credit=1
```

All you're missing is the querystring, and you'll just add that like so :

```
document.location.search = '?credit=1';
```

Comment: actually I was wrong, the url looks like this before it will redirect, `sample.com/administration/new_players/`

Comment: Then it won't work, you'll need to get those values from somewhere, and since you already are using PHP in your script, you can just echo them as strings right where the variables are, just remove the javascript concentenation and echo the PHP values into the url string.